# Setting up cocos2dx + windows8 + android

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x

I'm try to setting up cocos2dx to work with my Windows 8 and porting the project to Android.
I followed the official tutorial for windows 8 and visual studio 2012. However, I do not have any of the proj.* folders. Is there any way to create them? I can successfully run the code on Visual Studio, but I don't know how to port the code.
Here're the folders I currently have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdQkx.png
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdQkx.png]

Answer (score 1):

To create the proj.* folders you use a Python 2 program, which is in:

cocos2d-x-2.2.3\tools\project-creator\create_project.py

You'll need to install Python 2 (not 3) if you don't already have it installed.

You'll need to import the proj.andoid folder into a working Android Development Kit environment (eclipse) and NDK (native development kit). If you don't have this, it's not that easy but this guide is pretty good:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/37122

You might find it easier just to use Linux instead.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/23/topics/35386

To be honest, if your target environment is Android I wouldn't use Windows and Visual Studio as the starting point, but instead use Linux or Mac.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood - I though you were using Visual Studio because you wanted to port from Android to Windows Phone.  I've amended my answer.